# how to join two tables using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to join two tables using HQL or Criterial

Tables are

- Cart table(cartId,bookid,customeremailid,quantity)
- Book table(bookId,bookName,bookPrice,bookQuantity)

My sql query is like this

```
select count(c.cartId) as cartId,b.bookName as bookName,c.customeremailid as customeremailid,sum(b.bookPrice)as c.price,c.quantity from Book b,Cart c where  c.customeremailid='"+customeremailid+"' and b.bookId=c.bookid
```

which will give the count of `cartId` and sum of `bookPrice`

i am storing this result into `List<Cart>`

following is  `cart POJO` variables

```
private int bookid,cartId;
    private String customeremailid,bookName,bookDescription,image;
    private int quantity;
    private long price;
```

HQL Query :

```
String sql="select count(c.cartId) as cartId,b.bookName as bookName,c.customeremailid as customeremailid,sum(b.bookPrice)as price,c.quantity from Book b,Cart c where  c.customeremailid='"+customeremailid+"' and b.bookId=c.bookid";
             Query q=s.createSQLQuery(sql);
             Cartlist=q.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Cart.class)).list();


             for(Cart c :Cartlist)
             {
                 System.out.println("in cart : "+c.getCartId());
                 System.out.println("in cart : "+c.getPrice());
             }
```

Iam not getting how to do it in Hibernate

kindly suggest 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Joins using hibernate Criteria example code below:

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .createAlias("kittens", "kt")
    .createAlias("mate", "mt")
    .add( Restrictions.eqProperty("kt.name", "mt.name") )
    .list();
```

Reference: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations